# Select attributes or parameter with variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, select-object

Using this code I get the desired result:

```
Get-Service | select Name,Status
```

But the following code will not work, do you know why? I want the user to choose his own selection of attributes. I store the attributes in a variable like shown below. But it won't work:

```
$param = "Name,Status"
Get-Service | select $param
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create an *array* of the properties you want to select:

```
$param = "Name","Status"
Get-Service | select $param
```

Or you can split the string yourself to create an array:

```
$param = "Name,Status"
Get-Service | select ($param -split ',')
```

Comment: Thanks for your very quick response! Worked very fine with me!

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a hash table, like this:

```
$params = @{Property=@('Name','Status')}
Get-Service | Select @params
```

And even add some extra parameters, like this:

```
$params = @{
            Property=@('Name','Status');
            First=10;
            }
Get-Service | Select @params
```